# Which "man" is the male pigeon referring to?

Tags: doctor-dolittle, dr-dolittle-1998

Funny fantasy movie *Dr.Dolittle (1998)*

Dr. Dolittle reviving the talking tiger in the hospital which is
surrounded by cops. After they both saw cops, a female pigeon
says to a male pigeon:

> Female Pigeon: Are you OK?
>
> Male Pigeon: The **man**'s comin' down hard, but we're holdin'  strong.
>
> Female Pigeon: I got such a chill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The Man" is an American slang term: "The Man is ... 'the establishment' put in place to 'bring us down.'" (Urban Dictionary).  The police (as in the asked about instance) are the most characteristic of "The Man," but it also includes the legal system, various government agencies, and generally anyone in a position of power who serves to "keep down" the poor, minorities, or the otherwise disenfranchised.